# Async always WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to figure out what the `async` & `await` keywords are all about, however the output isn't what I'm expecting.

The console application is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo called");
        var result = Foo(5);

        while (result.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, Status: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, result.Status);
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static async Task<string> Foo(int seconds)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, second {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
                    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
                }

                return "Foo Completed.";
            });
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Foo called
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 6, second 0.
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 6, second 1.
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 6, second 2.
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 6, second 3.
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 6, second 4.
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Thread ID: 10, Status: WaitingForActivation
Result: Foo Completed.
Finished..
```

I was expecting to see the status changing from `WaitingForActivation` once the method is started.

How can it stay in this state and be active?

Comment: And what do you expect status to be when `.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
` is called?

Comment: Hi @AlexeiLevenkov I assumed it would have changed to `Running` or maybe `WaitingForChildrenToComplete` as it's no longer waiting.

Comment: Neither of these would make sense in your case - see [TaskStatus Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) - task is not running and also not finished its own code... I believe the only one that makes sense is the one you see.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I don't get what you mean.  The `Foo()` method is running and is outputting the lines with `Thread ID: 6`.  If it's not running what's it doing?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Aas the problem seems interesting, I've checked that by replacing `Task.Delay` in `Foo` with long running loop instead (calculating complex math for milions of iterations), and status is still only `WaitingForActivation`

Comment: @KonradKokosa Cheers, as I said below, I tried it with a `Thread.Sleep()` as well and no change.

Comment: I think Lukazoid's answer explains the behavior, my comments above are somewhat wrong as they actually based on incorrect assumption what Task actually represent...

Comment: This is a very confusing topic and this question and answer have not cleared anything up for us future internet searchers.  Why can no one (NO ONE) explain async and await clearly?  No one has ever been able to explain this to me, at all.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For my answer, it is worth remembering that the TPL ([Task-Parallel-Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), `Task` class and `TaskStatus` enumeration were introduced prior to the async-await keywords and the async-await keywords were not the original motivation of the TPL.

In the context of methods marked as `async`, the resulting `Task` is not a `Task` representing the execution of the method, but a `Task` for the continuation of the method.

This is only able to make use of a few possible states:

- Canceled
- Faulted
- RanToCompletion
- WaitingForActivation

I understand that `Running`could appear to have been a better default than `WaitingForActivation`, however this could be misleading, as the majority of the time, an async method being *executed* is not actually running (i.e. it may be `await`-ing something else). The other option may have been to add a new value to `TaskStatus`, however this could have been a breaking change for existing applications and libraries.

All of this is very different to when making use of `Task.Run` which is a part of the original TPL, this is able to make use of all the possible values of the `TaskStatus` enumeration.

If you wish to keep track of the status of an async method, take a look at the [`IProgress(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, this will allow you to report the ongoing progress. This blog post, [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) will provide further information on the use of the `IProgress(T)` interface.

Comment: `IProgress` only seems to be a 4.5 interface, is there a way to emulate it in 4.0 world?

Comment: @BanksySan: Install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package.

Comment: If it is about old TPL why am i getting the same result when using `TaskFactory.StartNew` ? http://i.imgur.com/nCjtb3s.png http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your first assumption is right: an async method being executed is not actually running (i.e. it may be await-ing something else).  actually in my first answer i wanted to say something like this.

Comment: @Selman22 Because you are writing the status of the `Task` returned by `Foo`, and not the task returned by `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

Comment: Could you explain "In the context of methods marked as async, the resulting Task is not a Task representing the execution of the method, but a Task for the continuation of the method" and / or provide a reference?

Comment: @nh43de The task returned from `Task.Run()` inside Foo() is actually running. But the async method Foo() returns a task that representing a continuation. Imagine Foo() having multiple `await Task.Run()` calls inside and just `return "Foo Completed."` at the end of the method. How would Foo() represent multiple tasks? In the example it is exra confusing because `return await Task.Run()` looks like it just returns the Task returned from Run(), but that is not it.

Answer (score 29):

The reason is your `result` assigned to  the returning `Task` which represents continuation of your **method**, and you have a different Task in your method which is running, if you directly assign Task like this you will get your expected results:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 10; i < 432543543; i++)
            {
                // just for a long job
                double d3 = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(i, 5) - Math.Pow(i, 2)) / Math.Sin(i * 8));
            }
           return "Foo Completed.";

        });

        while (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, Status: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,task.Status);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", task.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

The `output`:

[image]

**Consider this for better explanation:** You have a `Foo` method,let's say it **Task A**, and you have a `Task` in it,let's say it **Task B**, Now the **running** task, is **Task B**, your **Task A** awaiting for **Task B result**.And you assing your result variable to your returning `Task` which is **Task A,** because **Task B doesn't return a Task**, it returns a `string`. Consider this:

If you define your result like this:

```
Task result = Foo(5);
```

You won't get any error.But if you define it like this:

```
string result = Foo(5);
```

You will get:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'string'**

But if you add an `await` keyword:

```
string result = await Foo(5);
```

Again you won't get any error.Because it will wait the result (string) and assign it to your result variable.So for the last thing consider this, if you add two task into your Foo Method:

```
private static async Task<string> Foo(int seconds)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, second {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
            }

            // in here don't return anything
        });

   return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, second {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
            }

            return "Foo Completed.";
        });
}
```

And if you run the application, you will get the same results.(WaitingForActivation) Because now, your Task A is waiting those two tasks.

Comment: As the problem seems interesting, I've checked that. There is no `Task.Delay` in `Foo`, I added long running loop instead, and status is still only `WaitingForActivation`

Comment: I thought `Task.Delay()` created a new task, so I waited on that.  If I change the `Task.Delay()` to a `Thread.Sleep()` I get the same output.

Comment: yes,it created a new task, and your actual task waiting that new task

Comment: @Selman22 wouldn't that make the status be `WaitingForChildrenToComplete`?

Comment: @BanksySan But `FooAsync` has not completed yet.

Comment: but in documentation it says: `The task has finished executing and is implicitly waiting for attached child tasks to complete.` Your task isn't finish,just waiting.

Comment: @Selman22 Would you be able to give me a code example that does give the status as `Running` or `WaitingForChildrenToComplete`?

Comment: @BanksySan actually, i try it, i added too long task and never call wait, but still it says WaitingForActivation :D Now i'm curious like you :D

Comment: i think i found the reason,wait, YES ! :D

Comment: This answer changes the meaning of the question to one purely about the TPL, and nothing to do with the async-await keywords. This is NOT an answer for the original question.

Comment: Just noticed... Sorry @Selman22, still, thanks for investigating it.

Comment: Actually my answer is correct and not changing the meaning of question,but i couldn't explain it very well :D if you can do this with your foo method and get running results,let me know.

Comment: @Lukazoid to get the running result i have to set my variable to my task without using await. could you tell me if i use await how can i get Running result?

Comment: @BanksySan could you check my answer again, i updated my explanation.i hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The answers got me on the right track. So the problem is that  functions marked with async don't return a task of the function itself as expected (but another continuation task of the function).

So its the "await"and "async" keywords that screws thing up. The simplest solution then is simply to remove them. Then it works as expected. As in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foo called");
    var result = Foo(5);

    while (result.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, Status: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, result.Status);
        Task.Delay(100).Wait();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result.Result);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

private static Task<string> Foo(int seconds)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, second {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
        }

        return "Foo Completed.";
    });
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Foo called
Thread ID: 1, Status: WaitingToRun
Thread ID: 3, second 0.
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 3, second 1.
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 3, second 2.
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 3, second 3.
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 3, second 4.
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Thread ID: 1, Status: Running
Result: Foo Completed.
Finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

this code seems to have address the issue for me.  it comes for a streaming class, ergo some of the nomenclature.

```
''' <summary> Reference to the awaiting task. </summary>
''' <value> The awaiting task. </value>
Protected ReadOnly Property AwaitingTask As Threading.Tasks.Task

''' <summary> Reference to the Action task; this task status undergoes changes. </summary>
Protected ReadOnly Property ActionTask As Threading.Tasks.Task

''' <summary> Reference to the cancellation source. </summary>
Protected ReadOnly Property TaskCancellationSource As Threading.CancellationTokenSource

''' <summary> Starts the action task. </summary>
''' <param name="taskAction"> The action to stream the entities, which calls
'''                           <see cref="StreamEvents(Of T)(IEnumerable(Of T), IEnumerable(Of Date), Integer, String)"/>. </param>
''' <returns> The awaiting task. </returns>
Private Async Function AsyncAwaitTask(ByVal taskAction As Action) As Task
    Me._ActionTask = Task.Run(taskAction)
    Await Me.ActionTask '  Task.Run(streamEntitiesAction)
    Try
        Me.ActionTask?.Wait()
        Me.OnStreamTaskEnded(If(Me.ActionTask Is Nothing, TaskStatus.RanToCompletion, Me.ActionTask.Status))
    Catch ex As AggregateException
        Me.OnExceptionOccurred(ex)
    Finally
        Me.TaskCancellationSource.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary> Starts Streaming the events. </summary>
''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> Thrown when the requested operation is invalid. </exception>
''' <param name="bucketKey">            The bucket key. </param>
''' <param name="timeout">              The timeout. </param>
''' <param name="streamEntitiesAction"> The action to stream the entities, which calls
'''                                     <see cref="StreamEvents(Of T)(IEnumerable(Of T), IEnumerable(Of Date), Integer, String)"/>. </param>
Public Overridable Sub StartStreamEvents(ByVal bucketKey As String, ByVal timeout As TimeSpan, ByVal streamEntitiesAction As Action)
    If Me.IsTaskActive Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException($"Stream task is {Me.ActionTask.Status}")
    Else
        Me._TaskCancellationSource = New Threading.CancellationTokenSource
        Me.TaskCancellationSource.Token.Register(AddressOf Me.StreamTaskCanceled)
        Me.TaskCancellationSource.CancelAfter(timeout)
        ' the action class is created withing the Async/Await function
        Me._AwaitingTask = Me.AsyncAwaitTask(streamEntitiesAction)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

I overcome this issue with if anybody interested. 
In myMain method i called my readasync method like

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => ReadData()));
```

Everything is fine for me now.