# Status = WaitingForActivation using Async method

Tags: c#, rest, api, oauth-2.0, async-await

I am trying to call the API using the following code.

```cs
static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string token)    
{
    string result = null;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        }
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Calling the method like this

```
var getData = GetData("<api-url>", token.access_token);
```

I am getting `Status = WaitingForActivation`

Does anyone can help me what I am doing wrong here. I tried to find solutions and I am able to get the results without `asyn` method but I could not find any solution with `asyn`method.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't fully understand the question.is it called like this? var getData = await GetData("<api-url>", token.access_token);

Comment: @phonemyatt Apologies i forgot to change the calling method. And yes its called like var getData = await GetData("<api-url>", token.access_token); but i am getting Status = WaitingForActivation

Comment: which Status is this, Task status ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830998/async-always-waitingforactivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` your `CallApi` method like this:

```
var getData = await CallApi("<api-url>", token.access_token);
```

This means that your calling method will also need to be `async` like this:

```
public static async Task MyCallingMethod(...)
{
    ...
    var getData = await CallApi("<api-url>", token.access_token);
    ...
}
```

If your calling method must be synchronous, then consider calling your API like this:

```
public static void MyCallingMethod(...)
{
    ...
    string getData = null;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        getData = await CallApi("<api-url>", token.access_token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
    ...
}
```

Also, using `HttpClient` inside of a `using` statement can be very dangerous. Please check this article: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

If you noticed, I used `ConfigureAwait(false)` in my code sample. You can learn more about this in the following article: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html